# Are Fed repo operations done through the discount window?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve, monetary-policy, central-bank

Recently the Fed performed repo operations to keep the effective Fed funds rate down and close to its target. Is this the usual way banks get loans from the discount window, using treasuries as collateral, or is it something new?

I've read that this is QE all over again, but that makes no sense to me because the banks buy the treasuries back the next day, so the Fed's balance sheet is only larger for one day, right?

Comment: This sounds more like an economics question than a personal finance question. Can you clarify how this relates to personal finance?

Comment: 1) It relates to money and we are on money.stackexchange.com. 2) Approved tags include "federal-reserve" and "monetary-policy" 3) Forecasting interest rates is important for investing

Comment: yeah, I know that is confusing with the site name snd all, but the FAQ specifically states that questions on economics not related to personal finance are off topic. https://money.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=Economics+

Comment: Why is monetary-policy an approved tag then?

Comment: Because the site is community moderated and sometimes mistakes happen.